# Calculations on a field $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ with min polynomial $P = x^3-2x^2+3x-5$

Tags: matrices, field-theory, linear-transformations

> Suppose we have a field $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ where the minimum polynomial of $\alpha$ is $P = x^3-2x^2+3x-5$
>
> Prove that the mulitplication-by-$\alpha$ map $\phi$ : $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha) \rightarrow  \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ given by $\phi(\beta) = \alpha\beta$ is a $\mathbb{Q}-$linear transformation

My reasoning:

Suppose $\beta, \gamma \in \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ and suppose $c$ is any scalar

$\phi(\beta + \gamma) = \alpha(\beta + \gamma) = \alpha\beta + \alpha\gamma = \phi(\beta)+\phi(\gamma)$

$\phi(c\beta) = \alpha c\beta = c\alpha\beta = c\phi(\beta)$

> Compute $\phi(1), \phi(\alpha), \phi(\alpha^{2})$

My reasoning:

$\phi(1) = \alpha1 = \alpha$

$\phi(\alpha) = \alpha\alpha = \alpha^{2}$

$\phi(\alpha^{2}) = \alpha\alpha^{2} = \alpha^{3}$

> Compute the matrix $A$ that represents $\phi$ with respect to the basis {$1, \alpha, \alpha^{2}$}

My reasoning:

I know that a matrix $A$ with respect to the basis {$1, \alpha, \alpha^{2}$} has columns with vectors $\phi(1), \phi(\alpha), \phi(\alpha^{2})$. Thus, I get the following matrix $A$:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \alpha^{2} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \alpha^{3}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I was wondering if my reasoning was correct or if I have made mistakes (which I believe that I have). Thank you in advance for any help given.

Comment: Everything except the matrix looks ok. You are assembling it wrong.

Comment: I am not really sure how to compute a matrix that represents $\phi$ with respect to the basis {$1, \alpha, \alpha^{2}$}

Comment: Also, since $\alpha^3-2\alpha^2+3\alpha-5=0$, you can write $\alpha^3$ as a linear combo of lower exponent alphas and $1$'s.

Comment: Check example 2.4 https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/galoistheory/tracenorm.pdf

Comment: Are there general rules to follow to produce such a matrix?

Comment: It's the usual way of constructing the matrix of a linear transformation, but instead of basis like $(1,0),(0,1)$, we have $1,\alpha,\alpha^2$. If you need a refresher on how to compute the matrix of a linear transformation, here's an example:
https://i.ytimg.com/vi/J2bjzpyW6ro/maxresdefault.jpg

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix

Answer (score 2):

Here's the matrix representation: 
$$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 5\\ 
1 & 0 & -3\\ 
0 & 1 & 2
\end{bmatrix}.$$

$\phi(1)=\alpha=0\cdot 1+1\cdot \alpha+0\cdot\alpha^2$.

$\phi(\alpha)=\alpha^2=0\cdot 1+0\cdot\alpha +1\cdot \alpha^2$.

$\phi(\alpha^2)=\alpha^3= 5\cdot 1 -3\cdot\alpha+ 2\cdot\alpha^2$.

Notice that on the right of the $\cdot$'s I am writing basis elements.

Comment: Thank you for the help :)

Comment: How did you get this matrix?

Comment: Idk how to format the comments so I editted the answer.

Comment: You are right that the column vectors are $\phi(1)$, $\phi(\alpha)$ and $\phi(\alpha^2)$, but they are written in terms of the basis $(1,\alpha, \alpha^2)$.
So for instance, we have $\phi(1) = \alpha = 0 \cdot 1 + 1 \cdot \alpha + 0\cdot \alpha^2$ and the coefficients in the linear combination above is what you see in the first column. The other columns are found in the same way.

Comment: Also, observe how the last column resembles the minimal polynomial -- this is no coincidence.